# Android button not working ErrorLog

Tags: android

I'm working on a app. But when I add a button and try to launch it, it crashes.

ERROR 2

```
  10-24 22:08:25.930: E/AndroidRuntime(600): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 22:08:25.930: E/AndroidRuntime(600): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.exaample.werkajb.Class2 }
10-24 22:08:25.930: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1545)
10-24 22:08:25.930: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
10-24 22:08:25.930: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
10-24 22:08:25.930: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
10-24 22:08:25.930: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:840)
10-24 22:08:25.930: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
10-24 22:08:25.930: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)
10-24 22:08:25.930: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at com.exaample.werkajb.MainActivity$1.button1Click(MainActivity.java:27)
10-24 22:08:25.930: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at com.exaample.werkajb.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:35)
10-24 22:08:25.930: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
10-24 22:08:25.930: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
10-24 22:08:25.930: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-24 22:08:25.930: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-24 22:08:25.930: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-24 22:08:25.930: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-24 22:08:25.930: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 22:08:25.930: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-24 22:08:25.930: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-24 22:08:25.930: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-24 22:08:25.930: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Class.2java

```
    package com.exaample.werkajb;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Class2 extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
    }


}
```

ERROR:

```
10-24 06:00:53.188: E/AndroidRuntime(620): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 06:00:53.188: E/AndroidRuntime(620): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=cp3.tutorials.Class2 }
10-24 06:00:53.188: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1545)
10-24 06:00:53.188: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
10-24 06:00:53.188: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
10-24 06:00:53.188: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
10-24 06:00:53.188: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:840)
10-24 06:00:53.188: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
10-24 06:00:53.188: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)
10-24 06:00:53.188: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.exaample.werkajb.MainActivity$1.button1Click(MainActivity.java:27)
10-24 06:00:53.188: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.exaample.werkajb.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:35)
10-24 06:00:53.188: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
10-24 06:00:53.188: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
10-24 06:00:53.188: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-24 06:00:53.188: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-24 06:00:53.188: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-24 06:00:53.188: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-24 06:00:53.188: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 06:00:53.188: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-24 06:00:53.188: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-24 06:00:53.188: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-24 06:00:53.188: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MainActivity java code:

```
package com.exaample.werkajb;

    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;


    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    {

        Button button1;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                private void button1Click()
                {
                    startActivity(new Intent("cp3.tutorials.Class2"));
                }

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch (v.getId())
                    {
                    case R.id.button1:
                        button1Click();
                        break;

                    }

                }
            });


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Class2.java code:

```
    package com.exaample.werkajb;

public class Class2 {

}
```

Layout activity main xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.exaample.werkajb.MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Open New Activity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.exaample.werkajb"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="Class2"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

How do I get it to work so it will open a activity that I make?

Comment: `new Intent("something")` creates an implicit `Intent`. The "something" is not a class name but an action.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you copied the code but didn't change everything. It still uses the old package `cp3.tutorials` while your package is `com.exaample.werkajb`.

You could change that or do something more natural and versatile:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, Class2.class));
```

Edit: When used inside e.g. `OnClickListener` in `MainActivity` use this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Class2.class));
```

Comment: Hello, when i add that it says: The constructor Intent(newView.OnClickListener(){}, Class<Class2>) is undefined

Comment: ohhh.. in short he is saying code copying is bad..understand it before you copy it..

Comment: @Gjaltema Class2 must extend ActionBarActivity or Activity. `Class2 extends ActionBarActivity { ... }`

Comment: I'm new and working 4 days to fix my button. Can u explain where i need to add witch code? Thank u

Comment: @Gjaltema In your `Class2.java` file change to: `public class Class2 extends ActionBarActivity`.   I don't think I can be any more clear than that.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `LogCat` displays this error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=cp3.tutorials.Class2 }
```

I think  that you have defined an incorrect package:

```
 startActivity(new Intent("cp3.tutorials.Class2"));
```

if your class `Class2` is located inside the package: `com.exaample.werkajb`, change your intent to:

```
 startActivity(new Intent("com.exaample.werkajb.Class2"));
```

**update**: according to your `AndroidManifest.xml`, that's the problem, the package where is located Class2 must be:

```
 package="com.exaample.werkajb"
```

Remember the Activity `Class2`  must extend from `Activity`

```
package com.exaample.werkajb;

public class Class2 extends Activity {

}
```

add a dot in your `AndroidManifest.xml` definition and you don´t need another intent filter with category `MAIN`, you can add even more activities:

```
  <activity
        android:name=".Class2"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
   </activity>
  <activity
        android:name=".Class3"
        android:label="MyClass3" >
    </activity>
  <activity
        android:name=".Class4"
        android:label="MyClass4" >
    </activity>
```

Read more about: **[Intents and intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)**

Comment: Hello, I changed, but when i start the app and press the button it still crash. I will add Class2.java in the main message.

Comment: Okee, But how can i choice a activity it needs to open?

Comment: Where do i have to add it? Like i want to open Test4.xml. Ty

Comment: your declaration into the AndroidManifest.xml for Class2 is incorrect, you don´t need an intent filter with action MAIN: <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> i have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Put a dot (.) before Class2 in manifest activity declaration. After all the changes you have made so far from comments and answers, this will help you.

```
<activity
        android:name=".Class2"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Seems you have used Intent constructor incorrectly. Try using this

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Class2.class));
```

Comment: Can you post your error if its not the one you were getting earlier

Comment: I added it, name: ERROR 2

Comment: It works, wow! Thank u. But how can i choice what activity it needs to open? I have Layout: Test, Test2, Test3 and Test4 Thanks. And also what i need to add if i want to add a other button on the same Activity but open a other Activity. Ty

Comment: on click of other button use something like startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Class3.class))

Comment: Could u plz write a code for me with 3 buttons that go to Test1, test2 And test3? Ty :)

Comment: your existing problem is solved here, Could you accept my answer as you said it worked.